# gsp parameter passing from controller

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

how can i pass parameters to a groovy server page via a controller that are not an instance of a domain class ?

Comment: May be related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/2063220/6509

Answer (score 22):

You put your parameters into the model object map returned to your GSP, for example:

```
def index = { def hobbies = ["basketball", "photography"] 
render(view: "index", model: [name: "Maricel", hobbies: hobbies]) }
```

Then you get those values accessing them by the name you use in your model map, for example:

```
My name is ${name} and my hobbies are:
<ul>
<g:each in="${hobbies}" var="hobby">
<li>${hobby}</li>
</g:each>
</ul>
```

That should display the following:

```
My name is Maricel and my hobbies are:

 - basketball
 - photography
```

Answer (score 8):

The clearest way is probably to return a map from your controller action:

```
...
def myAction = {
    [myGreeting: "Hello there, squire!"]
}
...
```

Now you can access that parameter in your GSP page (by default myAction.gsp):

```
...
<p><%= myGreeting %></p>
...
```

More details here:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.3%20Models%20and%20Views

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this :

In the controller:

```
def myaction = {
    String name = "Tony Danza"
    [name: name]
}
```

In the gsp page you can view the name like so:

```
<body>
    My name is ${name}
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You return the parameters in the closure of the controller that has the same name as the gsp.