# How to show and hide buttons in grails depending on the condition?

Tags: grails, button, controller, conditional-statements

In my controller I have conditions, for example if value is 80, then I need to show certain button in my view, if value is 50 then I need to show a different button in my view. How would I do this in grails?

Comment: [7.2.2.2 Logic and Iteration](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#tagLogicAndIteration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seem not to be a controller logic. You can just in the view do something like:

```
<g:if test="${val == 80}">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</g:if>
<g:else>
   <input type="button" value="a button">
</g:else>
```

If you want to send val from the controller to the view, its something like:

```
class TestController {
    def index = {
      ['val':80] //or [val: params.val] if you want to get it from parameters.
    }
```

}

Comment: Ya I did something like that, however how do you pass val? It seems my value for val from my controller is not being recognized by the view.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624214/gsp-parameter-passing-from-controller

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on the same page, you need javascript. 

If you want to render page according condition, try [<g:if>](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Tags/if.html) tag

Answer (score 0):

I feel a better way to do this is to use a tag library rather than having logic in your .gsp. Also you can reuse this logic if it is needed elsewhere in your application.

```
// in your gsp
<lib:showButtons myValue="$val"/>

// in your tag lib
def showButtons = { attrs ->
  def myValue = attrs.myValue
  def value = "Submit"
  def type = "submit"

  if(myValue != 80) {
    value = "a button"
    type = "button"
  }

  out << '<input type="$type" value="$value" />'
}
```