# groovy pass map to javascript from controller

Tags: javascript, grails

I am fairly new to Grails MVC and javascript.
I am encountering a problem wherein i want to pass a map object from the controller to a javascript function.
Currently two parameters are passed to the javascript function which are comma seperated and this works fine

```
eg. someControllerFunction() {

    variableLink = "j-javaScriptFunction-${stringArgs1},${stringArgs2}" // This is a link for an ajax call 

}
```

The javascript function structure looks like this

```
function someJavaScriptFunction (details) {

    var d = details.split(",");
    var strintArgs1 = d[0];
    var stringArgs2 = d[1];

    ajax":{
                    "url":"${request.contextPath}/controller/methodInController?strintArgs1=" + strintArgs1 + "&stringArgs2=" +stringArgs2 
                    },
}
```

The Controller function which is called in the ajax currently looks like this

```
methodInController (String strintArgs1,String strintArgs2){

    //some operation
}
```

Now i want to pass a map object from the controller function to the javascript function but i am not able to as the javascript considers the map as an invalid String object.

Below are the changes i have made to the three functions but i am getting an error during the ajax call saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string"

```
eg. someControllerFunction() {

    variableLink = "j-javaScriptFunction-${stringArgs1},${stringArgs2},${mapArg}" // This is a link for an ajax call 

}
```

The map object looks like this

```
mapArg = [a:[],b:[],c:[],d:[]]
```

The javascript function structure looks like this

```
function someJavaScriptFunction (details) {

    var d = details.split(",");
    var strintArgs1 = d[0];
    var stringArgs2 = d[1];
    var mapArg = d[2];

    ajax":{
                    "url":"${request.contextPath}/controller/methodInController?strintArgs1=" + strintArgs1 + "&stringArgs2=" +stringArgs2 + "&mapArg=" +mapArg 
                    },
}
```

The Controller function which is called in the ajax currently looks like this

```
methodInController (String strintArgs1, String strintArgs2, Object mapArg){

    //some operation
}
```

It might be something to do with the way i am passing it to the javascript function but i am not able to figure out the exact reason.
Could anyone please help me to understand what am i doing wrong.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might have to cast the map to JSON first (which would explain why its a string). See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2064341/1902587