# iterate list accessed using session

Tags: jquery, list, session, grails, gsp

I am looking to iterate list from java/grails in jquery like below

**Controller**

```
session.legendList = legendList // [Soham Shetty] list in controller set to session
```

**GSP**

```
<input type="hidden" name="legendList" id="legendListId" value="${session.legendList}">
```

**jQuery**

```
var filterList= $("#legendListId").val();
// also tried
// var arrLegendList = jQuery.makeArray( filterList );      
for(f in filterList){
     $('#impact-report-user-filter-dropdown').append($('<option>', {
                     value: filterList[f],
                     text:  filterList[f]
     }));
}
$("#impact-report-user-filter-dropdown").multiselect("refresh");
```

Which is not working its giving **one char** of string as f instead of **one element list**

Comment: So what does the *served* `<input ...>` look like?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="legendList" id="legendListId" value="[Soham Shetty]">`

Answer (score 2):

Client-side, `$("#legendListId").val()` returns a string, not an iterable list.

`for(f in filterList) {...}` will indeed iterate, but over each *character of the string*, including the square brackets, which is not what you want. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zaz656f0/).

By serving a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) representation of your list in the `<input>` element, javascript/jQuery will be able to parse `$("#legendListId").val()` into an array with [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Alternatively, pass your [Groovy list to javascript directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063220/correctly-pass-a-groovy-list-to-javascript-code-in-gsp).